# output of n-queens does not match expected output

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking, n-queens

I have implemented the n-queens problem. However, on comparing with an online solution, I have more combinations than the actual answer.

Below is my code

```
public class Queens
{
    static int rows = 5;
    static int cols = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] column = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
        fun(0, column);
    }

    /* j is basically each column */
    static void fun(int j, int[] column)
    {
        if(j == cols)
        {
            System.out.print("success : ");
            for(int k = 0;k<column.length;k++)
            {
                System.out.print(column[k]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            return;
        }

        /* Each column could have the queen in any of the rows */
        for(int i = 0;i <rows ;i++)
        {

            if(isValid(column,j,i) == 1)
            {
                int[] temp = new int[rows];
                for(int k = 0;k<column.length;k++)
                    temp[k] = column[k];

                column[j] = i;
                fun(j+1,column);

                for(int k = 0;k<temp.length;k++)
                    column[k] = temp[k];
            }
        }
    }

    static int isValid(int[] a, int row, int check)
    {
        int lastindex = 0;

        /* check if they're in the same row */
        for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i] == -1)
            {
                lastindex = i-1;
                break;
            }

            if(a[i] == check)
                return 0;
        }

        /* check if they're in the same diagonal */
        if(lastindex >= 0)
        {
            /* diagonal on the rise */       /* falling diagonal */
            if( (a[lastindex] == check-1) || (a[lastindex] == check+1) )
                return 0;
        }

        /* Note : It can't be in the same column since you're selecting only one for each column, the for loop */

        return 1;
    }
}
```

This is my output for the 5-queens problem. (In code, you can get any n, by changing the values of rows and cols accordingly and changing the array )

```
success : 13524
success : 14253
success : 24135
success : 24153 -
success : 25314
success : 31425
success : 31524 -
success : 35142 -
success : 35241
success : 41352
success : 42513 -
success : 42531
success : 52413
success : 53142
```

However, the ones marked with a hyphen at the end, are missing from an [online site](http://theory.cs.uvic.ca/amof/cgi-bin/e_quee.pl.cgi?program=Queens&n=5&output1=standard&textLIMIT=200&boardLIMIT=10&x=43&y=7) I used to compare the output

Please tell me the reason for these four incosistencies. (For 8-queen, my code above gives 5242 combinations in output, surely I'm doing something wrong in the isValid function)

EDIT : Thanks a lot vish4071, I have changed the isValid() function now and get the correct output; I wasn't aware that diagonal has to be checked at every step.

Code

```
public class Queens
{
    static int rows = 8;
    static int cols = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] column = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
        fun(0, column);
    }

    /* j is basically each column */
    static void fun(int j, int[] column)
    {
        if(j == cols)
        {
            System.out.print("success : ");
            for(int k = 0;k<column.length;k++)
            {
                System.out.print(column[k]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            return;
        }

        /* Each column could have the queen in any of the rows */
        for(int i = 0;i <rows ;i++)
        {

            if(isValid(column,j,i) == 1)
            {
                int[] temp = new int[rows];
                for(int k = 0;k<column.length;k++)
                    temp[k] = column[k];

                column[j] = i;
                fun(j+1,column);

                for(int k = 0;k<temp.length;k++)
                    column[k] = temp[k];
            }
        }
    }

    static int isValid(int[] a, int col, int check)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i] == -1)
                break;

            /* check if they're in the same row */
            if(check == a[i])
                return 0;

            /* check if they're in the same diagonal */
            if( Math.abs(check-a[i]) == (col-i) )
                return 0;
        }

        /* Note : It can't be in the same column since you're selecting only one for each column, the for loop */

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason is simply your code does not match the optimum algorithm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check for diagonal is wrong. Don't use `lastindex`. Check for `same diagonal` for all values in `a` which are not `-1`.

I'd explain using one of your outputs (you put hyphen against) as example. Lets take `24153`.

Lets say your `a` is now `[2,4,1,-1,-1]`, ie. you are now about to fill index `3`. Your last index will be `1` and in a matrix, (2,1) and (3,5) don't lie in a same diagonal. So, it accepts 4th value as 5 `not being in the same diagonal`, while it is in same diagonal with your value at index `0`, ie. `2`, since (0,2) and (3,5) lie in same diagonal. So, check for all values.

Comment: thanks a lot. Have edited the isValid() function above. Please have a look.

Answer (score -1):

With answer on 5242 combination when it should be 92 normally the issue is only checking a pair of coordinates beside each other and not checking the ones not beside each other